# Convert date to year-month-day format with Painless

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have dates in this format: `2018-07-24T08:27:59.259Z`. What is the best way to convert this to `2018-07-24` in Painless? Looking through the Painless API reference, I realise there are methods such as `getYear()`, `getMonth()` and `getDayOfMonth()`, but I was wondering if there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this without having to mess up with dates is to simply split on the `T` character, like this:

```
POST test/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.date = /T/.split(ctx._source.date)[0]"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, clever. Simple is best I suppose.